# Premature end of file using JAXB and Unmarshaller. The xml fromt he response looks valid to me

Tags: xml-parsing, jaxb

I don't know what to do anymore. Everything seems correct; input/output.

I generate xml file and send to some service to validate.

The response is:

```
11:10:34,922 INFO  [STDOUT] printing out the input stream
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Response>
    <Method name="XML/Release/New" time="2013-04-23T15:10:35.1446238Z">
        <ResponseStatus>100</ResponseStatus>
    </Method>
</Response>
finished printing out the input stream
11:10:34,922 INFO  [STDOUT] got the unmarshaller
11:10:34,925 ERROR [PRNDataAccessUtil] Caught an error: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception: [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.] : null
```

The code:

```
try {
            out = connection.getOutputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = PRNPostNewsReleaseUtil.createNewsReleaseXml(newsRelease);
            bos.writeTo(out);

            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class.getPackage().getName());
            in = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            System.out.println("printing out the input stream");
            String line;
            while((line = inp.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println("finished printing out the input stream");

            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            response = (Response) unmarshaller.unmarshal(in);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Caught an error: " + ex + " : " + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (null != in) connection.disconnect();
        }
```

Comment: I struggled with this for a long time. And It got solved without me changing anything. I can only guess it may be an error related to the eclipse or the weblogic server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting the error because the `InputStream` has been advanced to the end during the output. Assuming the buffer in your `BufferedReader` is large enough to contain the whole XML document you can reset it after outputting and then unmarshal that.

Comment: hmmmm sounds probable. i will test that. i will delete the sysouts, just needed to see the content.

Comment: that did the trick! still strange though, i have another method that actually posts this input and i also do the sysout of the output, somehow that works without a problem. thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

One time happened to me that I was using the wrong class name to build the JAXBContext object, so when I tried to marshall an object, an empty XML file was created, thus making the unmarshaller fail.

So make sure the JAXBContext object is instantiated with the class you're trying to marshall.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to note here is even if you are not reading the buffer explicitly in code but have a expression watch that reads the input, it would end up having the same effect of incrementing the stream head. Figured that out after spending hours on debugging this exception.